# Getting a list of lists without using List<List<string>> in F#

Tags: f#

I have this function here:

```
let ProcessFile (allLines: string list) = 
    let list = new List<List<string>>()

    let rec SplitFile (input: string list) =
        if input.Length <> 0 then
            list.Add(new List<string>(input.TakeWhile(fun x -> x <> "")))
            let nextGroup = input.SkipWhile(fun x -> x <> "").SkipWhile(fun x -> x = "")
            SplitFile (Seq.toList nextGroup)

    SplitFile allLines |> ignore
    list
```

It is given the contents of a file as a list of strings and takes each group that is seperated by empty lines as a seperate list, giving me a list of lists.

My question is, is there a better way to do this with a yield that give me something like a string list list instead of me having to use new List< List< string>>? As this doesn't seem particularly neat to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more idiomatic solution might be:

```
let processFile xs =
  let rec nonEmpties n = function
    | [] as xs | ""::xs -> n, xs
    | _::xs -> nonEmpties (n+1) xs
  let rec loop xs =
    seq { match xs with
          | [] -> ()
          | ""::xs -> yield! loop xs
          | xs ->
              let n, ys = nonEmpties 0 xs
              yield Seq.take n xs
              yield! loop ys }
  loop xs
```

where the nested `nonEmpties` function counts how many non-empty elements are at the front of the given list and returns both the count and the tail list after the last non-empty element, and the `loop` function skips empty elements and yields sequences of non-empty elements.

Some interesting characteristics of this solution:

- Fully tail recursive so it can handle arbitrarily long sequences of non-empty strings and sequences of sequences of non-empty strings.
- Avoids copying by referring back to the input list.

On test input of 1,000 sequences of 1,000 strings this solution is 8x faster than yamen's and 50% faster than Tomas'.

Here is an even faster solution that begins by converting the input list into an array and then acts upon array indices:

```
let processFile xs =
  let xs = Array.ofSeq xs
  let rec nonEmpties i =
    if i=xs.Length || xs.[i]="" then i else
      nonEmpties (i+1)
  let rec loop i =
    seq { if i < xs.Length then
            if xs.[i] = "" then
              yield! loop (i+1)
            else
              let j = nonEmpties i
              yield Array.sub xs i (j - i)
              yield! loop j }
  loop 0
```

On test input of 1,000 sequences of 1,000 strings this solution is 34x faster than yamen's and 6x faster than Tomas'.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is quite readable to me, but using `TakeWhile` and `SkipWhile` recursively is fairly inefficient. Here is a simple functional recursive solution:

```
let ProcessFile (allLines: string list) =
  // Recursively processes 'input' and keeps the list of 'groups' collected
  // so far. We keep elements of the currently generated group in 'current'  
  let rec SplitFile input groups current = 
    match input with 
    // Current line is empty and there was some previous group
    // Add the current group to the list of groups and continue with empty current
    | ""::xs when current <> [] -> SplitFile xs ((List.rev current)::groups) []
    // Current line is empty, but there was no previous group - skip & continue
    | ""::xs -> SplitFile xs groups []
    // Current line is non-empty - add it to the current group
    | x::xs -> SplitFile xs groups (x::current)
    // We reached the end - add current group if it is not empty
    | [] when current <> [] -> List.rev ((List.rev current)::groups)
    | [] -> List.rev groups

  SplitFile allLines  [] []

ProcessFile ["a"; "b"; ""; ""; "c"; ""; "d"]
```

Essenitally the same code can be written using `seq { ... }` as follows. We still need to keep the list of current groups using an accumulator (`current`) but we now return groups lazily using `yield` and `yield!` as we iterate over the inputs:

```
let ProcessFile (allLines: string list) =  
  let rec SplitFile input current = seq {
    match input with 
    | ""::xs when current <> [] -> 
        yield List.rev current
        yield! SplitFile xs []
    | ""::xs -> 
        yield! SplitFile xs []
    | x::xs -> 
        yield! SplitFile xs (x::current)
    | [] when current <> [] -> 
        yield List.rev current
    | [] -> () }

  SplitFile allLines []
```

Comment: Nice answer but I'd recommend using pattern matching instead of equality on lists. So match over both `input` and `current` and use a pattern to check for empty `current` instead of `current <> []`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like one liners:

```
let source = ["a"; "b"; ""; ""; "c"; ""; "d"]

source                                                                       // can be any enumerable or seq
|> Seq.scan (fun (i, _) e -> if e = "" then (i + 1, e) else (i, e)) (0, "")  // add the 'index'
|> Seq.filter (fun (_, e) -> e <> "")                                        // remove the empty entries
|> Seq.groupBy fst                                                           // group by the index
|> Seq.map (fun (_, l) -> l |> Seq.map snd |> List.ofSeq)                    // extract the list only from each group (discard the index)
|> List.ofSeq                                                                // turn back into a list
```

The biggest problem here is that `Seq.groupBy` will read the entire list into memory, but you're doing that anyway. There are implementations of `groupBy` that will only look at adjacent entries and that would be sufficient, and will let you input the file as a `Seq` instead (for example, using `File.ReadLines` rather than `File.ReadAllLines`).

Answer (score 0):

How about using plain old List.fold

```
let processFile lines =
([], lines) ||>
List.fold(fun acc l -> 
    match acc with
        | [] when l = "" -> acc        // filter empty lines at the start of the file
        | [] -> [[l]]                  // start the first group
        | []::xss when l = "" -> acc   // filter continous empty lines
        | xs::xss when l = "" ->       // found an empty line, start a new group
            let rxs = List.rev xs      // reverse the current group before starting a new one
            []::rxs::xss
        | xs::xss -> (l::xs)::xss)     // continue adding to the current group
|> List.rev
```